# JBoss AS 7 : how to find the modules to exclude?

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x

I'm trying to deploy a Hibernate-based web application on JBoss 7 1.1.0.Final. The used Hibernate release is 4.2.21.Final. I'm having all sorts of issues that I can only presume to be classpath clashes. Hibernate, dom4j, ... to name a few.

If I'm not mistaken, when not having the liberty to change JBoss configuration, the solution is to provide WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml with a list of modules to exclude.

Is that a correct assumption ?

For starters, I've been trying to solve the infamous dom4j class cast exception. Excluding the module 'org.dom4j' does not help. I've also tried to exclude all modules depending on it. And those depending on those. Etc ... In the end removing the dom4j jar from the war file did work.

Alas, we are developing a web application containing a different release of Dom4j, Hibernate & all. We can't upgrade Hibernate on the JBoss instance and the same application has to run on different application servers too. So we can't remove the jars from the war file either.

My question is how does one find out what modules to exclude ? To solve the classpath clashes.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Not yet. This is part of a long compatibility test of our application with all kinds of JEE 6 application servers. We're fighting Glassfish now. :-)

Comment: Cool. All the best with that!

Answer (score 0):

For lack of better understanding, i have been using a very primitive way of dealing with issues like this one in JBoss. I just search the modules/system/layers/base directory of JBOSS_HOME for reference to the offending jar. That gives you a list of exclusions.

But sometimes this list turns out to be pretty long and you can't really exclude everything in it. In that case, the jars that you would want JBOSS to use (and not the ones bundled with it, DOM, Hibernate etc in your case) can be added as a custom module. This module can be then added as a global module in standalone.xml :

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.1">
            <global-modules>                
                <module name="my.custom.module"/>
            </global-modules>
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>
  </subsystem>
```

You also need to add this `<my.custom.module>` as a dependency to any other custom module you might have defined.

This has worked for me more than once. Hope it helps you too.

Comment: Thanks ! As soon as I'm back to JBoss, I'll try this. :-)